# When should I use runuser command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My question is quite simple:
When should I use `runuser` to run a command as another user when I am `root`, instead of `sudo` or `su` command?

Looks like they all are same, I really don't get the difference.

Comment: A Stack Overflow question should be about _a specific problem you actually face_, encountered during the course of software development. Consider [unix.se] for general UNIX tool questions.

Comment: In particular, there's an excellent survey of the available tools at [How do I drop root privileges in shell scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132663/how-do-i-drop-root-privileges-in-shell-scripts) over on [unix.se]. Several of the options there are _only_ for deescalating from root, and so can be installed without the setuid bit -- making them safer than `sudo` or `su` to have present on a system.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>(Answering Community Wiki to avoid getting rep for answering a clearly-offtopic question).</sub>

`runuser` is *only* for dropping permissions. Thus, it can be installed on systems designed by someone too cautious to permit `su` or `sudo`, both of which require a setuid bit (and so can escalate an arbitrary unprivileged user to root in the presence of a bug or misconfiguration; bugs in `sudo` in particular are not unheard of).

If you're writing software for such a system, you *must* use `runuser`.

If you're writing software to be run on *completely arbitrary* systems, and don't want to depend on setuid executables, you might want to choose something less Linux-specific than `runuser` -- personally, I'm fond of `chpst` from `runit`.

If you're writing software to be run on completely arbitrary systems, and don't care about any of this, use whatever you personally prefer.

Comment: you mean "too cautious to permit su or **sudo**"?

Comment: Indeed, I do. (If I'm building a high-security embedded system I don't use those tools. Both of them but especially sudo have a history of vulnerabilities, and on top of that there's risk of misconfiguration. It's safer to have explicitly setuid/setgid precompiled binaries [with permissions that only make to them runnable by the user you want to allow to perform an escalation] that run an exact execve with an exact environment and argument list).